# Depletion N-Channel MOSFET and the making of the depletion zone

Tags: mosfet

I want to learn on how MOSFETS work, particularly the creation of the depletion region.  But have seen conflicting information.  Consider an n-channel depletion MOSFET.  What I have seen is that the when the gate voltage is made more negative, the MOSFET will conduct less current.  Is this right?  How does the depletion layer get made?  Are there good references for this?  Really something authoritative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an enhancement-mode N-MOSFET, you have P-doped silicon in the channel region. As a positive charge is brought onto the gate, electrons get "pulled" into the channel region until the P-doped material undergoes inversion (there are so many mobile electrons in it that it effectively behaves as if it was N-doped). At that point, a channel is created, and the MOSFET conducts. (The conductive channel is a continuous "N-Path" from drain to source.)

If, on the other hand, you create an N-MOSFET that already has an N-doped channel between drain and source, it'll be conductive without any gate voltage applied. You can now do the reverse of the process described above: When you apply a negative charge to the gate, the resulting electric field pushes electrons out of the channel. As you add more charge, so many electrons will leave the channel that it again undergoes inversion and effectively behaves as if it was P-doped, at which point the MOSFET stops conducting.

Enhancement-mode and depletion-mode MOSFETs operate in exactly the same way. The only difference is whether the conductive channel is absent at zero gate voltage (enhancement-mode) or present at zero gate voltage (depletion-mode). You can even build a MOSFET that's somewhere between enhancement-mode and depletion-mode with a threshold voltage of exactly zero volts.

Note that the term "depletion-mode MOSFET" has nothing to do with the "depletion" that a semiconductor material can undergo. The process behind the switching of a MOSFET is *inversion*, not depletion.

Comment: Would the P-Doping start close to the oxide, or close to the interface between the n-channel and p-substrate?

Comment: Where exactly inversion occurs first is highly dependent on the doping profile of the channel. Ideally, all parts of the channel would invert at the same time, but that's unlikely in a physical device.

Comment: According to your description, it would first occur close the oxide? Right?

Comment: I require some references that describe physical devices.  Where should I look for such information?

Comment: A quick Google search turned up these papers: https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/apec/1996/060657.pdf https://oro.open.ac.uk/39056/1/Stefanov_ProcSPIE_8859-17%282013%29.pdf

Comment: Are there any books about devices with adequate coverage?